# MPC with Law of Excluded Middle is not equivalent to CPC

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have seen it said that MPC (Minimal Propositional Calculus) with LEM (Law of Excluded Middle; $A \lor \neg A$) is not equivalent to CPC (Classical Propositional Calculus), but I would like help finding a proof for this fact.

### Notation

MPC means Minimal Propositional Calculus,

IPC means Intuitionistic Propositional Calculus,

CPC means Classical Propositional Calculus,

LEM means Law of Excluded Middle ($A \lor \neg A$),

DNE means Double Negation Elimination ($\neg \neg A \vdash A$),

EFQ means Ex Falso Quodlibet ($\bot \vdash A $).

### Facts

I know that:

IPC = MPC + EFQ

CPC = MPC + DNE

CPC = IPC + LEM.

And so we see:

CPC = MPC + EFQ + LEM.

### Goal

My goal is to show

CPC $\neq$ MPC + LEM.

### Approach

This can be done by either showing that LEM does not imply EFQ:

$\neg A \lor A  \not \vdash_{MPC} \bot \rightarrow B $,

equivalently,

$\not \models_{MPC} (\neg A \lor A) \rightarrow (\bot \rightarrow B)$

or that LEM does not imply DNE in MPC:

$\neg A \lor A  \not \vdash_{MPC} \neg \neg B \rightarrow B $.

or equivalently

$\not \vdash_{MPC} (\neg A \lor A) \rightarrow (\neg \neg B \rightarrow B)$.

### Difficulties

I am having trouble proving any of these. I am not sure how to prove that something is not a theorem; in CPC I would just use the contrapositive of completeness, but here that does seem to work; I would have thought to use some intermediate multi-valued Godel logic $G_n$ between CPC and IPC, but it seems like these statements are validities in $G_n$ for any $n$. Any advice for how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't checked this in detail, but try $G_3$ with $\bot$ changed to be the other non-$\top$ element.

Comment: What do you mean by changing $\bot$ to be the other non- ⊤ element? $v(\bot)=0$ for all truth assignments $v$, by definition. So $\bot \rightarrow B$ will always evaluate to $1$ for any truth assignment.

Comment: In minimal logic, you don't have EFQ and there is no constraint on $\nu(\bot)$.

Comment: I am aware you don't have EFQ in MPC. In any Godel logic, you do have $v(\bot)=0$,  since $\bot$ after all is just a simplification of $A \land \neg A$, which always evaluates to $0$ given the definition of $\neg$.

Comment: To be honest I am not sure what your suggestion is. Could you explain it in more detail please?

Comment: In a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3758195/excluded-middle-double-negation-contraposition-and-peirces-law-in-minimal-log/3770853#3770853) I was pointed to the following [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.57.6941), which should also contain an answer to your question (cf. Proposition 3). The main intuition is that LEM fails to derive the explosion principle, whereas DNE can do that.

Comment: I didn't thoroughly check the following. Seems to work, though. Consider the truth tables for CPC, but where $A\to B=0$  when $A,B=0$ and $\lnot A=1$ whatever the value of $A$. MPC+LEM is sound with respect to these tables. But they afford counterexamples to both EFQ and DNE.

Comment: @Léreau Proposition 3 does state what I want to show, but the linked paper doesn't seem to contain a proof, just a statement. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @HermógenesOliveira I can see that editing the truth-tables for CPC gives counterexamples to EFQ and DNE, but could you show me how MPC+LEM is sound with respect to this semantics? Furthermore, why does showing that one rule #1 is sound with respect to an some semantics and rule #2 is not sound with respect to that semantics show that rule #2 is not derivable from rule #1? This may be a very basic question, sorry.

Comment: Soundness is shown by checking that the rules of MPC+LEM preserve the designated value under the semantics. Now, if $\not\Vdash EFQ$ in this semantics, then by soundness + modus tollens, $\not\vdash EFQ$.

Comment: @HermógenesOliveira It doesn't seem as if MPC+LEM preserve the designated value under the semantics. For example, $\rightarrow$ intro fails to preserve the designated truth value, in the case that $B$ is provable from $A$ (hence we can apply the intro rule) but $B$ and $A$ are both assigned false (in which case $A \rightarrow B$ is false. So I don't this semantics is sound with respect to MPC+LEM.

Comment: I'm sorry. You seem to be thinking about *completeness*. If neither $A$, nor $B$, nor $A\to B$ are being assigned "true", how is this supposed to show that the rule is failing to preserve truth? Another indication that there may be some confusion: is not that "the semantics is sound with respect to MPC+LEM", but the other way around.

Comment: No worries. I am just asking for the case of $\rightarrow$-Intro. In this situation, we do a subproof using A as an assumption and obtain B. From the semantic side, this means that if A is assigned true, then we assign B true. But it may well be the case that A gets assigned false, and B also gets assigned false. Nonetheless the hypothetical that if A true then B true might still hold. So we may have $A \rightarrow B$. But under your semantics $A \rightarrow B$ is false, and so $\rightarrow$-Intro does not preserve tautologies. Apologies for the phrasing error of soundness of x w.r.t y.

Comment: I think you may be thinking that I am talking about $\rightarrow$-Elim. I am talking about the introduction rule, $\rightarrow$-Intro, which makes no requirement on the truth-value of $A$ or $B$ besides the fact that $A$ being true gives $B$ as true.

Comment: As an explicit example, it seems that these MPC+LEM is not sound with respect to these semantics, as $\vdash A \rightarrow A$, but $ \not \models A \rightarrow A$ since under the truth assignment that sends A to false, $A \rightarrow A$ is false.

Comment: Yes. This last one is a proper counterexample to soundness of MPC+LEM with respect to the semantics that I proposed.